# How do I Get the distinct List of Special Characters from a File using GREP or SED?

Tags: unix, find, grep, special-characters

I have a file which contains about 30000 Records delimited by '|'. I need to get a distinct list of special characters only from the file.

For Eg: 
123|fasdf|%df&|pap,came|! 
234|%^&asdf|34|'":|

My output should be: 
|%&,!^'":

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks,
Velraj.

Comment: What is your definition 'special' character?

Answer (score 4):

```
grep -o '[|%&,!^":]' input | sort -u
```

You have to list all your special characters inside brackets.

This will return each unique special character on its own line. If you really need a string with these characters you have to remove newlines afterwards, e.g.:

```
grep -o '[|%&,!^":]' input | sort -u | tr -d '\n'
```

**UPDATE:**

If you need to remove all characters which are not from 'a-zA-Z0-9' set then you can use this one:

```
grep -o '[^a-zA-Z0-9]' input | sort -u | tr -d '\n'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will not know what all the special characters i will get in the file. I just wanted to print all the characters other than 0-9, a-z and A-Z.

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo "123|fasdf|%df&|pap,came|! 234|%^&asdf|34|'\":|" \
 | { tr -d '[[:alnum:]]'; printf "\n"; } \
 | sed 's/\(.\)/\1_/g' \
 | awk -v 'RS=_' '{print $0}' \
 | sort -u \
 | awk '{printf $0}END{printf "\n"}'
```

**output**

```
!"%&',:^||
```

You can replace the first line `echo ....` with `cat fileName`

Comment: Your output is not distinct (two vertical bars), but OT wanted it to be distinct I suppose.

Comment: @dying_sphynx : I keep forgetting that `print` in the `END` will print the last $0. I've fixed my solution, thanks for your feedback and good luck.